# Stripe API Error - Missing required param: amount - PHP library

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I have implemented a Stripe payment, but the problem is that I am continuously getting this error:

> {status: 500, error: "Missing required param: amount."}

As can be seen in the code, I have all the parameters, but still I do not know why this error is coming up. Here is the code I am using:

```
public function process(){
    try {
        Stripe::setApiKey('sk_text_key');
        $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                     "amount" => 2000,
                    "currency" => "USD",
                    "card" => $this->input->post('access_token'),
                    "description" => "Stripe Payment"
        ));
    } catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
        // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 500, 'error' => $e->getMessage()));
        exit();
    }
}
```

This is the javascript I am using to submit the form:

```
$(function() {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');
    $form.submit(function(event) {
        $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
        $form.find('.submit').val('Please wait...');

        Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
        return false;
    });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) 
{
    if (response.error) {
        alert(response.error.message);
    } 
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url('payment/process');?>',
            data: {access_token: response.id},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                if(response.success)
                window.location.href="<?php echo base_url('booking/thankyou'); ?>";
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Stripe are  you using?

Comment: what I can see - you're trying to  set token as CARD....per my mind it's "source". And as well....try to check the version of stripe used. Like example from my side: $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
         "amount" => 20000, // amount in cents
         "currency" => "usd",
         "source" => $token,
         "description" => 'Additional payment'
         ));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you are using a legacy code, in the newer versions of Stripe you can make the `Charge` like this:

```
// Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 2000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "description" => "Stripe Payment",
  "source" => $token,
));
```

See more examples [here](https://stripe.com/docs/charges).

Comment: Class 'Stripe\Charge' not found

Comment: This is how I am calling it on my controller payment require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');

Comment: Why not using namespace? Anyway, try with including this one: `require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/Stripe/lib/Charge.php');`

Comment: okay iI beleive the library I am using is incorrect can you please refer from hwere I can download

Comment: You can get the latest Stripe.js from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js), and the PHP library from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries#php-library)